# why data in data tabel is not deleting without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have delete button, and when I press this button It is working and deleting the row but I should refresh the page to disappear that row. How can solve this problem and deleting the row without refreshing the page?

actions:

```
   deleteItem({commit}, pk) {
          axios.delete(`/myurl/${pk}`)
               .then(() => {
                 commit('removeItem', pk)
                }).catch(function (error) {
              //eslint-disable-next-line no-console
              console.log(error)
          })
       },
```

mutations:

```
  removeItem: (state, pk) => (state.allLists = 
       state.allLists.filter(item => item.pk !== pk)),
```

button:

```
  <v-data-table
       :items="allLists"
       :headers="headers"
       :search="search"
  >
       <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
           <v-row>
               <v-btn
                     small
                     text
                     dark
                     color="primary"
                     class="mb-2"
                     @click="del(item.pk)"
                >
                    <v-icon>mdi-delete</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </v-row>
        </template>
   </v-data-table>
```

methods:

```
 methods: {
            ...mapActions(['fetchList', 'deleteItem', 'addItem']),

           del(ev) {
                 this.deleteItem(ev)
                },
          },
    }
```

Comment: I don't know enough about Vue.js to realy know whats going on but you call a function `commit()`. So if you are using a html form and say submit it will send the data to the server and in a database commit will end your transaction. So  maybe you'll find some guidance with the API manual.

Answer (score 1):

Your mutation `removeItem` is actually returning `state.allLists = state.allLists.filter(item => item.pk !== pk)`.

This is because you are using round brackets `()`. You should use curly brackets `{}`. Your mutation should look as following:

```
removeItem: (state, pk) => {
    state.allLists = state.allLists.filter(item => item.pk !== pk)
}
```

Generally speaking you want to avoid mutating the original array. It would be better to find the index of the item you want to remove and splice it. For example:

```
removeItem: (state, pk) => {
    const index = state.allLists.findIndex(item => item.id === pk.id);
    state.allLists.splice(index, 1);
}
```

This way when you access the state in your component it should be reactive and render the correct values without having to reload the page.

By the way how are you accessing `allLists` in your component?